# Invariant error plot for an arbitray system of ODE

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

i try to use `InvariantErrorPlot` command for a generic system of ODE but i find only example with pre-building equations from Mathematica Packages. This is one of them:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
system = GetNDSolveProblem["PerturbedKepler"]
vars = system["DependentVariables"]
H = system["Invariants"]
time = {T, 0, 290};
step = 1/25;
Met = {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10, 
   "PositionVariables" -> {Subscript[Y, 1][T], Subscript[Y, 2][T]}};
sol = NDSolve[system, time, Method -> Met, StartingStepSize -> step, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{Subscript[Y, 1][T], Subscript[Y, 2][T]} /. sol], 
 Evaluate[time]]
InvariantErrorPlot[H, vars, T, sol, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

Now the question is simple: can I modify it to use `InvariantErrorPlot` for my equations? And if so, how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just spelunking a little I got this for the harmonic oscillator problem:

```
eqs = {y[1]'[T] == y[2][T], y[2]'[T] == -y[1][T]};
iniconds = {y[1][0] == 1, y[2][0] == 0};
invariants = {1/2 (y[1][T]^2 + y[2][T]^2)};
vars = {y[1][T], y[2][T]};
system = {eqs, iniconds, vars, {T, 0, 10}, {}, invariants, {}};
erksol = NDSolve[NDSolveProblem@system, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
InvariantErrorPlot[invariants, vars, T, erksol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The two empty lists on the `system` definition requires some more work to find out what they are.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a very good starting point for me !